# Extração de dados na Web com Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Up.. Seguinte galera...
Estou escrevendo um código com o Framework scrapy para buscar e extrair alguns dados. Sou novo nisso! O código a seguir teoricamente teria que buscar e extrair, porém ele não extrai os dados quando eu executo. Estou usando a class item que existe dentro do arquivo items. A questão é que o código não acusa erro na execução, no cmd aparece as informações da requisições realizadas e tals, mas não faz o download dos dados e nem salva. Se alguém puder me ajudar e dar uma luz eu serei grato.

[image: Spider para buscar e extrair dados]

Comment: Não poste seu código em imagem. Copie e cole na pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, tenta rodar o comando:

```
scrapy crawl pensador -o pensador.json
```

Ele vai salvar os dados em um JSON.

Mas a maneira mais correta a se fazer é tratar os dados crawleados nos pipelines.py

Lá você pode salvar no banco de dados.
Dá uma olhada na documentação:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html